# Only run code when connected to wifi Batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a batch file only if it's connected to Wifi and specifically not Bluetooth LAN

I have this code but it returns this and still runs the code while an internet connection isn't present

```
Node - DEVICENAME
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
```

Code:

```
@echo off

For /f "usebackq" %%A in (
  `wmic path WIN32_NetworkAdapter where 'NetConnectionID="Wi-Fi"' get NetConnectionStatus`
) do if %%A equ 7 (goto end)

<code to run>

:end
```

Comment: You goto to the label end only when %%A is 7, but in your output is no line contains a 7

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've done that now, thanks. @Compo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop:

```
wmic path WIN32_NetworkAdapter where 'NetConnectionID="Wi-Fi"' get NetConnectionStatus |find "7" >nul && goto :eof
echo code to run
```

If you want to make it more secure, instead of `find "7"` use `findstr /rc:"^7 *$"`

(your original approach fails because the `=` has to be escaped: `... where 'NetConnectionID^="Wi-Fi"' get  ...` and due to the unusual `wmic` output, there are `CR` in your `%%A`, which messes up the `if` syntax; You can see both issues with `echo on` (at least you can see that strange things happen))

The output of WMIC is also the reason for that strange `findstr` pattern, I used. (there are trailing spaces after the `7`).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already know the name of the wireless interface connection, *(which is a configurable property)*, then you could probably use something more like this:

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NIC
 Where "Not NetConnectionID Is Null And NetConnectionStatus='2'" Get
 NetConnectionID /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN^
 Show Interfaces 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L ": %%G" 1>NUL^
 && <code to run>
```

If your target systems are still using Windows 7, *(which has a known issue locating some of the XSL files used in the `/Format` option)*, then the following alternative may work for you:

```sh
@For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NIC Where
 "Not NetConnectionID Is Null And NetConnectionStatus='2'" Get NetConnectionID
 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%H In ("%%G") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe^
 WLAN Show Interfaces 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /L ": %%H" 1>NUL^
 && <code to run>
```

*You would obviously change your provided, and replicated above, `<code to run>`, to one or more actual valid commands*